# Fixed-base exponentation with preprocessing

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation

Is anyone aware of an in-depth study of algorithms using preprocessing to compute fixed-base exponentiations? Assuming I am willing to do arbitrary computation in the preprocessing phase (but not store an arbitrary amount of data afterward), what is the optimal time/storage tradeoff here?

Note: I have read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) on Wikipedia as well as [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11962/speed-up-modular-exponentation-with-fixed-base-and-modulus) from 9+ years ago. (However, the link provided there to a paper that may help answer my question no longer works.)

Comment: The link in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11963/555) should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you -- I think that pretty much answers my question, since the paper is exactly what I am looking for and google scholar doesn't show any improvements to that paper

Comment: Don't forget to vote up the earlier question / answer. Besides giving back recognition & higher score on e.g. search engines, it may also gain more interest of other cryptographers; maybe they know a better trick.